# Ngrok tunnel https via config

Tags: ngrok, tunnel

I am having some issues finding how to properly write my ngrok.yml file such that it will start the tunnel using https. What I have at the moment is the following:

```
tunnels:
  invenutory:
    proto: http
    addr: 44328
    host_header: localhost
```

The issue here is that if I use the url ngrok gives me it does not connect (i test this by seeing if it hits my healthcheck endpoint, it does not). However, if I start ngrok using the following command:
`ngrok http https://localhost:44328 -host-header="localhost:44328"` then it will properly hit my endpoint. How can I make my config file act the same way?

Edit:

If I set the `addr` to be `addr: "https://localhost:44328"` then it does properly use https, but for some reason this seems to me like an incorrect way of doing it.

Comment: IMO you need to add the port number to the `host_header` value: `host_header: localhost:44328`. In the examples from the documentation the ports used are default ports, so they are not needed. In your command line you are specifying also `host:port` and not only `host`. Quote: The "Host" header field in a request provides the host and port
information from the target URI

Comment: I did try setting host_header to be that, but it still looks like both https and http of the ngrok tunnel were still mapping to http only instead of http going to http and https going to https. Is it a limitation of having a free account?

Comment: I see. I am not sure about the free account, but it does not look like it.

Comment: It is alright for now I guess, that work around I posted in my edit should suffice for my needs for now

Comment: Your solution: set the `addr` to be `addr: "https://localhost:44328"` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `bind_tls` flag to the config file to create only HTTPS tunnels as per the [docs](https://ngrok.com/docs#tunnel-definitions)

```
tunnels:
  invenutory:
    proto: http
    addr: 44328
    host_header: localhost
    bind_tls: true
```

Answer (score 1):

For `ngrok` 3.4.0 this works for me:

```
version: "2"
authtoken: 1qv8wlalala
tunnels:
  api:
    addr: "https://localhost:57335" 
    schemes:
      - https
    inspect: false
    host_header: "https://localhost:57335"
    proto: http

  portal:
    addr: "https://localhost:44365"
    schemes:
      - https
    host_header: "https://localhost:44365"
    proto: http
```

Answer (score -1):

To start a https only tunnel with a ngrok http tunnel, use the flag [`-bind-tls`](https://ngrok.com/docs#http-bind-tls).

This is unrelated to how you use `addr`, which can be used to let ngrok know if your local server is listening for http or https.

From the [docs](https://ngrok.com/docs#http-local-https):

> ngrok assumes that the server it is forwarding to is listening for unencrypted HTTP traffic, but what if your server is listening for encrypted HTTPS traffic? You can specify a URL with an https:// scheme to request that ngrok speak HTTPS to your local server.