# How do I connect my reactjs frontend and ASP.NET Core backend on ngrok?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, ngrok

I'm new to this and I'm trying to connect my frontend and backend so that it can receive and send data. But I can't seem to get it to work.

This is the code for launchsettings.json on backend:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:56440",
      "sslPort": 44385
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebAPIv1._1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

While this is the code for proxy.js in frontend:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
import * as Path from "../Productivity/state/apiRoutes";

module.exports = app =>{
    app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware('/department',
        {
            target : 'https://localhost:44385/api',
            changeOrigin : true
        })
    )

}
```

What do I need to do to have both frontend and backend to run on ngrok?

I've tried the connecting frontend and backend by opening up ngrok.yml and change the code inside to:

```
version: "2"
authtoken: 
tunnels:
    frontend:
        proto: http
        addr: 3000
    backend:
        proto: http
        addr: 44385
```

and `run ngrok start frontend backend` on ngrok.exe

I can open the frontend url from ngrok and get errors when I try to login to the website-application since it cant connect to the backend, and then I get ERR_NGROK_3004 on backend url from ngrok.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've overall found a solution, sorry I'm new. Nothing wrong with the code above at all, just need to use https properly.  [Ngrok HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65674701/ngrok-tunnel-https-via-config)

My ngrok.yml file:

```
version: "2"
authtoken: 
tunnels:
    frontend:
        proto: http
        addr: 3000
    backend:
        proto: http
        addr: "https://localhost:44385"
        host_header: localhost
```

Then just connect the frontend to the backend by changing the URL paths as Jason said, change it to the ngrok url, I also changed the .env URL path.

In my case it was:

```
module.exports = app =>{
    app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware('/api',
        {
            target : 'https://ngrokurlsample.ngrok-free.app/api',
            changeOrigin : true
        })
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you host your applciation? Kestrel or IIS?  The `launchsettings.json` file is only applicable to Visual Studio or other compilers, if your project is launched through Kestrel, you need to add the following code.

```
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000");
```

In my sample you could find I am using 5031, you need change to 5000.

[image]

**Suggestion**

1. In your visual studio choose `WebAPIv1._1`, then start.
2. I haven't tried to use ngrok.yml, so suggest you use command to expose the backend application port. By using

   ```
   ngrok http 5000
   ```
3. You can change setting like below

   ```
   "WebAPIv1._1": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "swagger",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
   }
   ```
4. The change the targetUrl,like below

   ```
   module.exports = app =>{
       app.use(
           createProxyMiddleware('/department',
           {
               target : 'https://fd78-167-220-255-54.ngrok-free.app/api',
               changeOrigin : true
           })
       )

   }
   ```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. 

I've tried to do what you've said but it still can't connect to the backend. I can't access my API through ngrok, it just gives an error: ERR_NGROK_3004 when I try `ngrok http 5001`

I can easily access my frontend using ngrok but can't do much since it can't access the backend. 

Both frontend and backend works on localhost, no errors and completely works. 

I've tried running the frontend by itself using `ngrok http 3000`, but nope still cannot do anything at all.